# Android Apk Split for different screen sizes

Tags: android, google-play, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, multiple-apk

Hi I am in a spot of bother I am not sure how to configure my build.gradle script to build Apks for the supported screen sizes.
And I am confused as to what Google play uses to check which apk to install does it check the screen size of the device or the screen desity?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I got what you want, but if you want just to separate resources by density, the right way to do it is configure the res folder, not build.gradle file.
In the res folder, you can configure layouts and drawables by density or even by height/width.
Do not over kill using gradle for this purpose, just use regular res folder.

BTW, Play store do not define density or correlated stuff, your app defines the resolutions to be displayed in each device, according to the configurations you've done in your res folder.

Comment: If you really want to work this way, you could check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599840/gradle-builds-for-every-resource-folder

Comment: Thank you filipe appreciate your advice!