# Android gradle load and compile libraries based on architecture

Tags: android, gradle, abi

I've included opencv in my android app using the following statements:

```
compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '0.11'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '2.4.11-0.11', classifier: 'android-arm'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '2.4.11-0.11', classifier: 'android-x86'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.6.1-0.11', classifier: 'android-arm'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.6.1-0.11', classifier: 'android-x86'
```

Now only two out of the four are used, which is a waste of space and probably also speed. Is there a way to only load/compile libraries which belong to an architecture? I've read [Gradle android build for different processor architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268647/gradle-android-build-for-different-processor-architectures) but this one uses the libs folder and therefore has its own includes. I have all libraries imported through gradle.

Answer (score 5):

You could use gradle flavors ([documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies)).

```
productFlavors {
    arm {
        ...
    }

    x86 {
        ...
    }

    all {
        ...
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    // For arm
    armCompile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '2.4.11-0.11', classifier: 'android-arm'
    armcompile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.6.1-0.11', classifier: 'android-arm'

    // For x86
    x86Compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '2.4.11-0.11', classifier: 'android-x86'
    x86Compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.6.1-0.11', classifier: 'android-x86'

    // For all
    allCompile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '2.4.11-0.11', classifier: 'android-arm'
    allcompile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.6.1-0.11', classifier: 'android-arm'
    allCompile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '2.4.11-0.11', classifier: 'android-x86'
    allCompile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.6.1-0.11', classifier: 'android-x86'
}
```

Then use the build variant you want.

Comment: Does this automatically select the right architecture? Or is this about creating 2 different APK's?

Comment: It's create two apks depending of selected flavor. You can add another one with all architectures. You can see my edited answer

Comment: But I would like one apk that people download from the google play store and then depending on their architecture, compile/load the right libs..

Comment: Compilation is done before uploading apk on the play store....
Check http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SupportedFilters to see how to use CPU architecture filter with different apk's