# How can I get the "current" build type in build.gradle file?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I want to do something like this:

```
 productFlavors {
        favor1 {
            buildConfigField 'String', 'SERVICE_URL', BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equals("test") ?
                    '"oneThing"' :
                    '"anotherThing"'
        }
        //more flavors
}
```

But obviously I get an error when `BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equals("test") ?`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739163/how-to-get-current-buildtype-in-android-gradle-configuration first result on google

Comment: Did you find an adequate solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
   applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER = "PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER"
        def SERVER_URL = "SERVER_URL"

        def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name
        def buildType = variant.buildType.name

        if( flavor == "Demo") {
            buildConfigField "String", "PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER", "\"identifier_DEMO\""
        }
        else if( flavor == "Test") {
            buildConfigField "String", "PRODUCT_IDENTIFIER", "\"identifier_TEST\""
        }

        if( buildType == "debug" ) {
            variant.buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", "\"https://myserver.com/debug\""
        }
        else if( buildType == "release" ) {
            variant.buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", "\"https://myserver.com/release\""
        }
    }
```

Then, from Java side:

```
String identifier = BuildConfig.HOTEL_IDENTIFIER;
String serverUrl = BuildConfig.SERVER_URL
```

will result in:

`DemoDebug`

```
identifier -> "identifier_DEMO"
serverUrl -> "https://myserver.com/debug"
```

`DemoRelease`

```
identifier -> "identifier_DEMO"
serverUrl -> "https://myserver.com/release"
```

`TestDebug`

```
identifier -> "identifier_TEST"
serverUrl -> "https://myserver.com/debug"
```

`TestRelease`

```
identifier -> "identifier_TEST"
serverUrl -> "https://myserver.com/release"
```