# Android, Gradle to allow certain buildtypes with certain productflavors

Tags: android, gradle

I have a basic gradle file below for android project. Wtih this file I have 4 build variants: fav1-debug, fav2-debug, fav1-release, fav2-release. How can I assign release to build with only fav2; debug to build with anything except fav2.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alock"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    productFlavors {
        fav1 {
            // Something
        }

        fav2 {
            // Something
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // Something
        }
        release {
            // Something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't forbid this. However you can throw an exception when irrelevant build variant chosen. There is many ways to detect `buildType` and `productFlavor` during the gradle build. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739163/how-to-get-current-buildtype-in-android-gradle-configuration) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621183/how-to-get-current-flavor-in-gradle).