# Android Gradle how to set variable depending on current buildType

Tags: android, gradle

How to set variable depending on current buildType, I have tried this

```
String url = "https://dev.myurl.com"
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'generateReleaseBuildConfig' || task.name == 'generateDebugBuildConfig') {
        if (task.name == 'generateReleaseBuildConfig') {
            url = "https://prod.myurl.com"
        }
    }
}
```

But no matter if the current buildType is Release or Debug, the tasks `generateReleaseBuildConfig` and `generateDebugBuildConfig` are both executed, so I never get the value depending on the current buildType. I specify that this variable is used later in build script and not in Java code.

I have tried several [solutions found in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739163/how-to-get-current-buildtype-in-android-gradle-configuration?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but none worked for me

Answer (score 5):

This example is from my own application. It's working fine

Put follow code on your `app\build.gradle`

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://..."'
        }
        release {
            ...
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://..."'
        }
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** sync your `gradle`

And then put follow call on your class

`String URL = BuildConfig.SERVER_URL`

Answer (score 0):

You can use buildConfigField. It looks like this:

```
 buildConfigField('String', 'API_URL', "\"URL\"")
```

Place it in gradle, under different buildType. And to get it use this:

```
 BuildConfig.API_URL
```

That will return this value depends of buildType

UPDATE

Are sure you placed it correctly?

```
 buildTypes {
         debug {
             //...
             buildConfigField('String', 'API_TEST', "\"URL\"")
         }

         release {
             //...
             buildConfigField('String', 'API_TEST', "\"URL\"")
         }
     }
```

Comment: I get an error : Could not get unknown property 'BuildConfig' for task ':xxx:yyyy' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.

Comment: Please take a look at example, and if you can not find any mistake, please provide your buildTypes code fragment.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I am using it in a task just before generateReleaseBuildConfig or generateDebugBuildConfig., maybe at this moment buildConfig is not already defined