# Android studio flavor dimensions processed all, not selected one

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-flavordimension

I have a flavor dimensions in module build.gradle file, and gradle build process runs through all build variants whatever actual build variant is. Here is module build.gradle:

```
flavorDimensions 'type', 'jnitype'
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            dimension 'type'
            versionNameSuffix '.demo'
        }
        production {
            dimension 'type'
            versionNameSuffix '.production'
        }
        usejni {
            dimension 'jnitype'
            versionNameSuffix '.usejni'
            copy {
                from('../jnilib/data') {
                    include 'sdk_data.gpu'
                    .... 
                }
                into 'src/main/assets/data'
            }
        }
        nojni {
            dimension 'jnitype'
            versionNameSuffix '.nojni'
            delete('src/main/assets/data/*.*')
            packagingOptions {
                exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/sdk.so'
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

So no matter what build variant selected, demoUsejni or demoNojni, gradle runs through 'usejni' and then 'nojni' variants - it copies files and libraries, and then deletes them. I used gradle debug to confirm this.

How can I tell gradle to use just a selected build flavor?

AS 3.5.2, gradle plugin 5.4.1, android build tools 3.5.2.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more.. Does it runs both flavors no matter what is selected.

Comment: @vijaypalodes
>Does it runs both flavors no matter what is selected?
Exactly. While building, it runs thru 'usejni' flavor and copies files, and then thru 'nojni' flavor and removes files and libraries. All in one build pass, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the solution is found: use gradle task name to check for required flavor. For  an action at compile type gradle task name will be ":module_name:assembleFlavor1Flavor2...FlavornBuildtype". So i will check for "assemble" and "Nojni"/"Usejni".

```
String taskName = "";
if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.size > 0)
    taskName = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.get(0)

usejni {
    dimension 'jnitype'
    versionNameSuffix '.usejni'
    if (taskName.contains("Usejni") && taskName.contains("assemble")) {
        copy {
            from('../jnilib/data') {
                include 'sdk_data.gpu'
                .... 
            }
            into 'src/main/assets/data'
        }
    }
}
nojni {
    dimension 'jnitype'
    versionNameSuffix '.nojni'
    if (taskName.contains("Nojni") && taskName.contains("assemble")) {
        delete('src/main/assets/data/*.*')
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/sdk.so'
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Like a charm!

Hint for solution found in this answer: [How to get current buildType in Android Gradle configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739163/how-to-get-current-buildtype-in-android-gradle-configuration)