# app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am importing a library module named "wear" in my project and while building, I am getting this:

```
Error : A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.   
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.   
Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :wear.
```

What does it mean? How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Could you solve this yet? I am facing the same issue while building for React Native through Android Studio.

Comment: Are you using composite builds? I have this error when I build with `--include-build`, but without it I have another one: `Could not find libmylib.aar (com.package:libmylib:1.0-BETA-SNAPSHOT).
  Searched in the following locations:`, even though the "location" in which it searches is the right link. In my case, I get those errors with gradle 3.4.1, but not with gradle 2.14.1 (i.e. the latter works fine).

Comment: @rarahat02, Did you found any solution for this issue. Am also facing the same issue. If so, please suggest the possible way to fix the issue.

Comment: not yet @SenthilMg

Comment: one of the reasons for this problem is renaming directory name for the module. so don't change folder of your modules

Answer (score 38):

This error usually occurs when Gradle cannot find a particular component. I experienced this when trying to use the Salesforce React Native Android example.

The error message you get looks like the one you posted ... in my case it was

```
Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :libs:SalesforceReact.
```

I found my Gradle settings file ( called `settings.gradle` ) in the projects `android` directory. The start of it looked like this

```
rootProject.name = 'SmartSyncExplorerReactNative'

def libsRootDir = new File( settingsDir, '../node_modules/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/libs' )
include ':app'

include ':libs:SalesforceReact'
project( ':libs:SalesforceReact' ).projectDir = new File( libsRootDir, 'SalesforceReact' )
```

In this case, the path given in `libsRootDir` did not exist (as these libraries actually came from a different repository which I cloned and then pointed this path to!).

Once I had corrected the path, save the settings file and reran, everything worked smoothly.

I hope this helps,
Jonathan.

Comment: This just happened to me and thanks to your answer I found that the npm module I was pointing to in the path was not installed! Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I have faced same issue when i update android studio 3.0 and following solutions works for me

```
implementation project(path: ':yourModule', configuration: 'default')
```

This solution will work if you are using `Gradle` 4.1 and above and `Gradle Plugin Version 3.0.0` and above.

I hope this will work for you

Comment: For some more info about why this fix works see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718663/gradle-error-configuration-declares-dependency-which-is-not-declared

Answer (score 5):

I found this error too. So, I noticed that my *settings.gradle* was searching for a path that didn't exist. Example: *(settings.gradle)*

```
project(':YourProjectV1').projectDir = new File('../YourProjectFolderV1/app/');
```

However, in my filesystem, the path was: ../YourProjectFolder**v**1

After syncing the names, the project was ok!

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue with a different set of modules.  I was finally able to resolve it by reinstalling the necessary modules via npm but with the `--save` flag.  i.e. `npm install --save module-name`

It looks like if you just have the `.iml` file in the module folder, it's not enough for the android studio to resolve it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the project itself lays inside the target project root folder:

```
...
 |-wear
      |-app
```

So in order to include it properly you have to define path that points to that inner folder:

'setting.gradle':

```
include ':app', 'MyLibraryProject'
project(':MyLibraryProject').projectDir = new File("X:\\SOME_PATH\\wear\\app")
```

'app\build.gradle' **(Main project)**

```
dependencies {
...
compile project(':MyLibraryProject')
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this errors too, it turns out that there are a library path changed. Im using `react-native-maps` version `1.4`

In `settings.gradle` change the react-native-maps dependency path to

`...
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')`

It seems to me the installation manual is not updated

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered such a problem, when I was in the window10 compiler no problem, but I compiled a problem in Linux, I think this reason with the platform, I checked and found that my project name is with the case Named, and then I ***unified named lowercase letters***, and then build, found successful. ^ _ ^.

Answer (score 0):

for me, I just modify the line in settings.gradle:
project(':test').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '~/android-test')
to 
project(':test').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '/Users/Michael/android-test')
which means avoid using "~" in the settings.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just needed to add the submodule so I ran the following git commands in terminal:

`git submodule init
git submodule update` 
and then a rebuild!

Answer (score -1):

first: rm -rf node modules

then: npm i

then: Build -> Clean

then: Close Android Studio and Reopen. This time u should be promoted in the bottom area that react-native-maps needs to be installed. Click on the link and install it

Answer (score -3):

This case is you don`t install the plugin.Please you install the plugin.Such as "npm install -s wear"