# React native Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' ...project :react-native-linear-gradient

Tags: android, react-native, dependency-management

I'm trying to add `react-native-linear-gradient` to my project following these [instructions](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient#android) but after adding the dependency to the `app/build.gradle` file and tried to sync the project I got this error

```
Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-linear-gradient.
```

May be someone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

***UPDATE*** :

This my `app/build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-svg')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

and this is my `settings.gradle` file:

```
rootProject.name = 'DuluxTradePoints'
include ':react-native-svg'
project(':react-native-svg').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-svg/android')
include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')
include ':app'
```

Comment: Probably is related to files location. Check this [issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/159)

Comment: can you add part of build.gradle where you are adding this library?

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal check updates.

Comment: there should be some issue with path of the react-native-inear-gradient project. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929841/app-declares-a-dependency-from-configuration-compile-to-configuration-default

Comment: Check if the project path is correct which you are adding the dependency to.