# Error while using Github library in Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition

I want to create a **Speaker Recognition** Android app using android studio.

I came accross https://github.com/amaurycrickx/recognito Library in java.
But I am having difficulty in implementing it in Android.

First, I saved the recognito folder by copying it in libs folder (creating it manually) in my main directory of my android app.

Then, in `settings.gradle file -- include ':recognito'`

```
build.gradle app file --     compile project(':recognito')
```

After sync. getting the error -

```
Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :recognito.
```

I researched, [Gradle error: configuration declares dependency which is not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718663/gradle-error-configuration-declares-dependency-which-is-not-declared) It says that since build.gradle file doesn`t exists for the Recognito project. But how will it? Cos it contains only java files.

Please help ..

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.urvi.android.abc"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile project(':recognito')

}
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':recognito'
```

and the folder Recognito I copied has https://github.com/amaurycrickx/recognito/tree/master/recognito files. I did not copy from the initial path

Comment: Please share your full gradle files

Comment: this project seems old so it must be built on eclipse, anyway you can create a gradle by yourself for the project

Comment: can you please try include ':app','recognito' in settings.gradle? This is how I always do it and it works - not sure if 2 includes work

Comment: *Latest commit eae9ca1  on 8 Sep 2014* => When you read this, you know you have found yourself a gem. Use in production code for unexpected yet funny results...

Comment: @shadygoneinsane how to create a build.gradle file for this java project?

Comment: @ligi I tried, but did not work :/

Comment: Ah just seeing the library does not use gradle - the way you try it you can only add gradle libraries

Comment: @UrviG is your problem solved !

Comment: @shadygoneinsane I added all java files manually, changed the package name. Still having issues in using classes in Javax package and File classes which are supported in eclipse and not in android. So i need to figure out alternative to these classes..

Comment: @UrviG I understand this can be frustrating. [Anyways here is a library which I think I will serve you well let me know if you aren't able to use this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ujl4apql02vo0ck/recognito.zip?dl=0) :)

Comment: @shadygoneinsane Thanks! :) looks  useful, will try to use it in android. but there are some libraries of JAVAX package which are used in recognito and android wont use them. Will that problem arise when I will try to use this library u sent in my android project?

Comment: @UrviG I only compiled it, you can create a small test run and check :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this library has not been made to be used for Android app but Java application. It uses parts of the Java API not available for Android (like  javax.sound.sampled.*). Plus I'd not recommend to use any library not being updated in the last 3 years.

Comment: yes but.. Unable to get other open source speaker recognition API in java :/

Comment: In that case, you can maybe use this lib as a base to create your own, as the calculation and so on, should probably be the same for Android?

Answer (score 0):

The way you try to add the library it needs to have gradle build-files. I see 2 ways to solve the problem:

- create a jar from the library and include it this way
- use a service like jitpack to include the library

For generating the jar: 
 * clone the repo
 * cd recognito
 * mvn package

then you get:

```
Results :

Tests run: 53, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ recognito ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/ligi/git/3rd/recognito/recognito/target/recognito-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.318 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-07T11:58:23+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/302M
[INFO] --
```

there is your jar - now include it.

Comment: Thank you :) 
For step 1, is this https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm link alright?

Comment: Whats the difference between JAR and executable JAR?