# ERROR: configuration 'implementation' to configuration 'internalRelease' is not declared in the descriptor for project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

I've a `core` module that is the base of my app. This module have 2 flavors. When I try import it in my `app` module that has no flavor, I receive the following error:

```
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :core.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'implementation' to configuration 'internalRelease' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :core.
```

That's my core build.gradle configuration:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions 'target'

    productFlavors {
        internal {
            dimension "target"
        }

        external {
            dimension "target"
        }
    }

    dexOptions { preDexLibraries true }
}
```

And here is how i'm importing this module in my app module build.gradle:

```
 implementation project(path: ':core', configuration: 'internalRelease')
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @Donki I didn't

Answer (score -3):

Try using simply `implementation project(':core')` see link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44364851/8560690)

Comment: And how do I choose the flavor from core that I want to use?

Comment: It gives me this message: Cannot choose between the following variants of project :core:
          - externalReleaseRuntimeElements
          - internalReleaseRuntimeElements

Comment: Any luck with that issue? @Tgo1014

Comment: sry, but no luck @outlying I couldn't find a way to solve it