# PGB Phonegap Builder cordova-plugin-firebase - Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found

Tags: firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-android

We're receiving this error from PGB integrating plugin 'cordova-plugin-firebase'.

**EDIT**

**Plugin in use**

```
call-number 0.0.2 
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 
ourprojectname-plugin-firebase  2.0.5
cordova-plugin-calendar 4.6.0 
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 
cordova-plugin-app-event 1.2.1 
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3 
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.2 
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 >
cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.4.3
```

**PGB configuration**

```
<engine name="ios" spec="4.5.4" />
<engine name="android" spec="6.3.0" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.1.0" />
<preference name="pgb-builder-version" value="1" />
```

**Cordova cli 7.1.0**

**Android Studio 3.0.1**

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Script '/project/ourprojectname-plugin-firebase/ourprojectname-build.gradle' line: 28

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'project'.
    > Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.
```

Plugin was customized and currently push as a npm package currently. Here it's **build.gradle** file

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+' // Updated from 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
        compile project(':CordovaLib') // Android studio project build requirement
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:+'
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
           transitive = true
        }
    }

    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras.add({
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
        apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
    })
```

The classpath "com.google.gms:google-services" was updated with "+" due to the fact that locally on Android Studio is building correctly.

**Question**

1) Is some way to pass a custom gradle configuration to PGB ?

2) If not, how is possible to fix error reported ?

**EDIT**

About first question, we discover **app-extras.gradle** way to override or add some configuration for Android but is not enough.

Currently only way to build successfully android app is to use this suggestion:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44364851/6859885

And some other fix for externalizated plugin:

1) **compile project(':CordovaLib')** that allow to fix some dependencies for gradle about cordova test's method implementation;

2) Adding **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+** in plugin dependencies avoiding to specify package version due to a version conflicts between plugin in use.

Thanks in advance.