# Android studio switch jniLibs depends on build type

Tags: android, gradle

My Android Studio project contains 2 modules, one is `app`, which is an application, another is a library named `mymodule` referred by `app`.
I create two folders in `mymodule`:

```
src/main/jniLibs
src/debug/jniLibs
```

What I want is when building app in debug mode, `mymodule` switch `jniLibs` dir to `src/debug/jniLibs` and `mymodule` switch `jniLibs` to `jni/main/jniLibs` if build `app` in release mode, I just don't know how to configure in my `build.gradle`, can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build variants in Gradle for a Library Project in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451803/build-variants-in-gradle-for-a-library-project-in-android)

Comment: @azizbekian Android Studio's integration with jni has changed so much over the past three years that I don't think a 3 year old question should be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Could you post more information about your gradle version and the build.gradle for the native module, mymodule?