# Android library project not using correct resources for debug variant

Tags: android, android-resources, android-library

My problem is much as described in questions such as this: [Build variants in Gradle for a Library Project in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451803/build-variants-in-gradle-for-a-library-project-in-android)

That is, I'm making a library module with debug and release build types, and each build type has its own resources (for example in `strings.xml`).  However, the release resources are always selected even when building the debug variant.

Pretty much everything I'm reading indicates that this has been fixed in Android Studio 3.0, but I'm on 3.3 and still experiencing the problem.  One suggestion I've seen is to use `releaseCompile` and `debugCompile`.  Those are deprecated so I used the replacements:

```
debugImplementation project(path: ':myLibrary', configuration: 'debug')
releaseImplementation project(path: ':myLibrary', configuration: 'release')
```

That produces these errors:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@myAppDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :myLibrary.
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@myAppDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :myLibrary.
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@myAppDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :myLibrary.
Affected Modules: app
```

I've quadruple checked the spelling, and it matches the name of the library. 
I was doing this before that resulted in the incorrect behavior described above:

```
implementation project(':myLibrary')
```

From the library build file:

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {}
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    ...
```

I also have a "qa" build type that I have omitted from discussion, but I have no reason to believe that's relevant as I'm not currently attempting to build that type.  Any suggestions, or anything else I should add to the question?

Comment: It happens because strings.xml is a global resource in your project. To solve your problem i will need to understand why and what you are getting strings.xml inside your library. Maybe you are trying to get/thinking in a bad way.

Comment: I have various `strings.xml` files, for example one in the library's `main` source set and another in its `debug` source set.  In an app module, if the same resource is defined in both places when building the debug variant, the debug value will be used.  In my library module the value from the main source set is used rather than being overridden by the value in the debug source set.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: no way to do this currently nasch sorry

Comment: @FredGrott Well that's dumb!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

build-types `debug` and `release` are default [build-variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types); referring by `configuration` might only work for `productFlavors` (as the Android library [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) hints for).

- better use `implementation project(path: ":myLibrary")`
- with [source-sets](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourcesets) `main` and `debug`; optionally `release`.

`publishNonDefault` and `defaultPublishConfig` are only useful for [external publishing](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.TestedExtension.html#com.android.build.gradle.TestedExtension:defaultPublishConfig).

according to [issue 68778928](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68778928):

> Libraries always publish all their variants *now* so the DSL property has no effect.

one possible workaround is to add the already built artifacts by `classifier`:

```
artifacts {
    archives file: file('build/outputs/aar/my-library-debug.aar'), classifier: 'debug'
    archives file: file('build/outputs/aar/my-library-release.aar'), classifier: 'release'
 }
```

Comment: I am using `implementation project()` and that's what is showing the problem with always picking release resources (the documentation doesn't include the word "path" in its usage).  I have main, debug, and release source sets.  I tried the `artifacts` block but it seemed to have no effect.  I hope your first sentence is incorrect, and that there is a way to get this to work for build types.  I really don't want to create a flavor dimension that basically mirrors the build type - that sounds like a mess.  Thank you for taking the time to put this answer together.

Comment: @nasch the situation is that this once worked, but not works anymore since `3.0.0` ...linking built `JAR` or `AAR` packages seems to be the least overhead, without having to define `productFlavors`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. To get an AAR to link, I would need to build a library whether from this project or another.  When building that library, how do I select debug and release resources?

Answer (score 0):

You can change which varaint gets published from your library by adding following line to your library project:

`android {
    defaultPublishConfig "debug"
}`

Comment: This will not work, because I need to publish the debug variant for a debug build and the release variant for a release build.

Comment: Then add it only to debug variant block of your library.

Comment: That had no effect - still selecting release resources.